# Visualise focus and interaction in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to see how the page is interacted with during my tests, e.g. what elements currently have the focus and where the interaction happens (similar to what the Cypress UI does).

How can I most conveniently achieve this in Selenium for Python?

Comment: Are you running Selenium on Windows? Because that way it loads up a Chrome window and you can watch what it's doing.

Comment: In Java, I just run the test in debug mode and step through it. Is that possible with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily inspired by the helper function from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule#Function_to_add_a_stylesheet_rule to add global stylesheet rules into a page I created `add_css.js` (in the subfolder `helper_js`):

```js
/* global arguments */
(function (rules) {
    var styleEl = document.createElement("style");

    styleEl.classList.add("PART-OF-SELENIUM-TESTING");

    // Append <style> element to <head>
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

    // Grab style element's sheet
    var styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;

    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        var j = 1,
            rule = rules[i],
            selector = rule[0],
            propStr = "";
        // If the second argument of a rule is an array of arrays, correct our variables.
        if (Array.isArray(rule[1][0])) {
            rule = rule[1];
            j = 0;
        }

        for (var pl = rule.length; j < pl; j++) {
            var prop = rule[j];
            propStr += prop[0] + ": " + prop[1] + (prop[2] ? " !important" : "") + ";\n";
        }

        // Insert CSS Rule
        styleSheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + propStr + "}", styleSheet.cssRules.length);
    }

}).apply(null, arguments);
```

which I then loaded and injected into the page using:

```py
import pkgutil
add_css = pkgutil.get_data("helper_js", "add_css.js").decode("utf8")

# ...

driver.execute_script(
    add_css,
    [
        [":active", ["outline", "3px dashed red", True]],
        [":focus", ["outline", "3px dashed yellow", True]],
        [":active:focus", ["outline", "3px dashed orange", True]],
    ]
)
```

in order to add global styles for elements which are active or have focus.